# Cant get mongoDB document to update

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Pymongo, Python3. Really racking my brains. Tried `update_one()` and `find_one()`*and*`update()`. Tried with the mongo id `"_id"` as well as with a know ID that I set in each document. Nothing updates in the documents. Can anyone please show me where I m going wrong? 
See below for last attempts. Want to loop over all collections and all documents in each collection and update a specific field.

With `update_one()` and an `ID` I know to exist in the document:

```
for collection in collectionNames:
    for doc in movie_db[str(collection)].find():
        new_path = get_updated_poster()
        new_path_url = base_url + new_path
        result = movie_db.collection.update_one({'id':int(ID)},{'$set':{'poster_path':new_path_url}})
```

With find_one_and_update(), even tried with copying an "_id" to no avail  (note that I here also have "from bson.objectid import ObjectId" added:

```
for collection in collectionNames:
    for doc in movie_db[str(collection)].find():
        new_path = get_updated_poster()
        new_path_url = base_url + new_path
        result = movie_db.collection.update_one(
                     {"_id":ObjectId(id)}, 
                     {"$set": {
                         "poster_path": new_path
                     }
                     }, upsert=False)
```

Comment: Remove the type casts in conditions, then if you still have difficulties post the documents and conditions you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movie_db.collection.update_one` usually means to update one document in the collection named "collection".

You appear to be using `collection` to hold the name of your collection, so you probably need to use `movie_db[str(collection)].update_one`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Could you maybe just explain why this worked? I am indeed holding the name of the collection in the variable "collection". Is it because Im using a variable that I need to use the db[variableName] version rather than db.variableName?

Comment: Exactly, `db.collection` is sort of like a syntactical shorthand for `db.getCollection("collection")` or `db["collection"]` so it doesn't support use variable collection names.